# Script for running (testing) another matlab script?

Tags: matlab

I need to create a matlab mfile that will run another matlab file with default values given in a txt file. It's ment to be useful for testing programs, so that user may specify values in a txt files and instead of inputing values every time he starts the program, my script will give the program default values and user will only see the result.

My idea is to load tested file into a variable, change 'variable=input('...');' for variable = default_variable;, save it to tmp file, execute, and than delete tmp file. Is this going to do the job?

I have only two problems:

1) How to eliminate the problem of duplicated variable names - i mean this must work for all scripts, i don't know the names of variables used in tested script.

2) As I wrote before - is this going to work fine? Or maybe I missed a easier way to do it - for example maybe I don't have to create a tmp file?

I really need your help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have 3 suggestions: (1) Use functions instead of scripts. (2) Take a look at [MATLAB's unit test framework](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-unit-test-framework.html). (3) Consider using JSON-style text files for your input files; you can use [JSONlab](http://iso2mesh.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/index.cgi?jsonlab) to load them as [MATLAB structures](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) to pass input arguments to your functions.

Comment: That might be easier, I know, anyway I must create a SCRIPT to deal with SCRIPTS. That my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the person who has to edit the default values has access to Matlab, I would recommend `save`ing the values in a mat file and `load`ing them when needed. Otherwise you could just write a smalls cript that contains the assignment to certain variables, but make sure to keep this small. For example:

```
maxRuns = 100;
clusters = 12;
```

---

So much for setting up the defaults. Regarding the process my main advice is to wrap the thing that you want to test into a function. This way variables used in the code to call the 'script' will not interfere as a function gets its own separate workspace. Check `doc function` if you are not familiar with them.

Comment: That might be easier, I know, anyway I must create a SCRIPT to deal with SCRIPTS. Anyway changing script into function is a clever idea.